# updating the state with handle click event and passing to the parent component not effecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to pass the data to parent component using handleclick but its functioning fine.

But it sends data to the parent like
if I typed `option` it sends at parent `optio`
missing the last charactor.

Below is the call to the child component where onClickTitles I am fetching the data

```
  <CreateEvent onClickTitles={this.handlerPollsValue} initialValues={this.state.init} />
```

In the `CreateEvent` component here, this is my handleInputChange function

```
const [zValues, setValues] = useState('');

const handleInputChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues({
      ...zValues,
      [name]: value,
    });
// here setting the values
        onClickTitles(pValues);
      };
```

Where I am setting the `onClickTitles` values where `pValues` is the value I am setting using `setValues`

```
const pValues = [
    {
      title: zValues.option1,
      index: 0,
    },
    {
      title: zValues.option2,
      index: 1,
    },
  ];
```

Everything works well but not getting the last charactor of what I type in input.
(I am using multiple `<input>` compoennt for data inputs)

Can anyone help me here to resolve this?

Comment: You probably try to access a state (`this.state.value` or `value`) after either `this.setState({value: newValue})` or `setValue(newValue)`. Calling either of these two functions does not immediately updates the state, but merely queues the update. See [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](/q/54069253/3982562) and [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](/q/30782948/3982562) You should use `onClickTitles(newValue)` instead of `onClickTitles(value)`

Comment: Without more context it is most likely not possible to accurately give an solution to your problem. What is `zValues`? When is `pValues` set to the provided structure? Could you provide more context regarding the component?

Comment: @3limin4t0r Can you help me with this? I am very much stuck with this

Comment: @3limin4t0r here's full component code https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-goldberg-upbzl?file=/CreatePollComponent.js

Comment: `const [zValues, setValues] = useState("");` seems incorrect if you want to assign properties via `setValues`. Can you try `const [zValues, setValues] = useState({});`?